# Use constructor overload from within class constructor

Tags: java, constructor

As the title hints at, I am wondering if I am able to use functionality in a class's constructor from another constructor (overload) of the same class in Java.

Hopefully this code demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve (ignore the fact that `children` gets overwritten, bad example in this case):

```
class Node {
    int[] value;
    ArrayList<Node> children;

    Node ()
    {
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Node (int[] value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Node();
    }

    Node (int[] value, Node[] children)
    {
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>(Arrays.asList(children));
        Node(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the duplicate question, your call to other constructors must be the first line in the constructor.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Thanks guys!

Comment: I guess you are looking for: [Using this with a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)